# Select query with month and year condition

Tags: php, mysql

I have two query conditions here, and I would think that these queries would result in the same data, but they don't.

```sql
// 1st Condition:
WHERE month(jurnal.time) >= '01'
  AND month(jurnal.time) <= '06'
  AND year(jurnal.time)   = '2012'

// 2nd Condition:
WHERE jurnal.time  > '2012-01-01'
  AND jurnal.time <= '2012-06-30'
```

I want the first condition to result in the same data as the second conditions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You used a `>=` condition on the first part of the first test and a `>` in the second version, is this normal ?

Comment: First query has '>=', second query has '>'. Is it intentional or just a typo?

Comment: Damn, I lost this race of common senses. )

Comment: By the way, both [MONTH](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) and [YEAR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) return numbers - not strings.

Comment: Also would be interesting to know what's the type of `jurnal.time` column.

Comment: i want select data form begining of january 2012 until the last of june 2012, but i have only three parameter the first and the second month and the year.

Comment: could you give us some data samples from jurnal.time and as said the column type

Comment: data type of jurnal.time is date like this ('2012-01-01')

Answer (score 2):

1. Your first version includes `jurnal.time = '2012-01-01'`, whereas your second condition does not (owing to the use of `>` rather than `>=`).
2. It isn't clear from your question what is the data type of the `jurnal.time` column:

   - if it's `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`, your second example will not have included any time after `00:00:00` on June 30 so one must instead either take only the date part:

     ```
     WHERE DATE(jurnal.time) BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-06-30'
     ```

     or else ensure that the comparisons include all times of the day:

     ```
     WHERE jurnal.time BETWEEN '2012-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-06-30 23:59:59'
     ```
   - if it's `DATE`, this point will not have affected your examples but one can nevertheless simplify your second example to:

     ```
     WHERE jurnal.time BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-06-30'
     ```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the BETWEEN comparison operator with CASTs:

```
WHERE jurnal.time BETWEEN CAST('2012-01-01' AS DATE) AND CAST ('2012-06-30' AS DATE)
```

Be sure to cast the stings to the same type as the column of jurnal.time.

Comment: A string in the form `'YYYY-MM-DD'` is already a valid MySQL date literal: `CAST` is superfluous and achieves nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Your conditonals in the first query are trying to compare as if they were numbers the values returned from the date parsing functions, but i think they are just strings. '01' and '06' are interperted by sql as plain strings, not the numbers 1 and 6.

The second is sql is smart enough to convert the full date string representation into a date to use in the comparison.

Comment: I want the first condtional will return same result as the second conditional.

Comment: @wibi Yes, but the conditonals in the first query are comparing  numbers to strings.  The second query uses strings that which is sql is smart enough to compare dates. '06' and '01' make no sense in using greater than and less than.

Comment: i have modified the first conditional like this -- where month(jurnal.time)>=month('2012-01-01') and month(jurnal.time)<=month('2012-06-01') and year(jurnal.time=year('2012-01-01')  but the result still different with the second conditional

Comment: @wibi Those functions probably return string representations of the month, day, etc...  You can not get what you want by comparing the 2 character month and day string representations--i cant figure any way to make that clearer. Hope it helps head you to your answer